# How many minutes after the first instance is launched will Auto Scaling accept another scaling activity request?

Tags: amazon-web-services

### I'm preparing for AWS Solutions Architect Associate exam. I came across this question and answer but the answer is not convincing for me. Can someone help me in providing better explanation in a simple way? Here is my question-

**Question**: You have set up an Auto Scaling group. The cool down period for the Auto Scaling group is 7 minutes. The first instance is launched after 3 minutes, while the second instance is launched after 4 minutes. How many minutes after the first instance is launched will Auto Scaling accept another scaling activity request?

A. 11 minutes

B. 7 minutes

C. 10 minutes

D. 14 minutes

Answer: A

**Explanation**:If an Auto Scaling group is launching more than one instance, the cool down period for each instance starts after that instance is launched. The group remains locked until the last instance that was launched has completed its cool down period. In this case the cool down period for the first instance starts after 3 minutes and finishes at the 10th minute (3+7 cool down), while for the second instance it starts at the 4th minute and finishes at the 11th minute (4+7 cool down). Thus, the Auto Scaling group will receive another request only after 11 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

This question is related to the multiple instances being launched in the AutoScaling group.

You can configure your AutoScaling Group to launch One instance when CloudWatch Alarm triggers and You can also configure your AutoScaling group to launch more than one instances when CloudWathc Alarm triggers. This one is the second case.

As per [AWS Documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/Cooldown.html) :

```
It is common for Auto Scaling groups to launch more than one instance at a time. For example, you might choose to have the Auto Scaling group launch three instances when a specific metric threshold is met.

With multiple instances, the cooldown period (either the default cooldown or the scaling-specific cooldown) takes effect starting when the last instance launches.
```

So this explains why the answer is 11 mins :

1. You have two instances to be launched whenever autoscaling triggers.
2. Autoscaling happens, First instance launches at 3mins and second one launches at 4 mins.
3. If we go with the AWS Documentation, then "*the cooldown period takes effect starting when the last instance launches.*" The last Instance was launched after 4mins so autoscaling will receive another request after (4+7) 11 mins.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks